# How to make semicolon (;) as delimiter in java

Tags: java

I made a program that can parse .csv file to database,
I want to make semicolon as delimiter but I got some trouble here ~

This is my code CSVLoader.java

```
package id.co.lolo.coreservice;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;

public class CSVLoader {

private static final String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO ${table}(${keys}) VALUES(${values})";
private static final String TABLE_REGEX = "\\$\\{table\\}";
private static final String KEYS_REGEX = "\\$\\{keys\\}";
private static final String VALUES_REGEX = "\\$\\{values\\}";

private Connection connection;
private char seprator;

/**
 * Public constructor to build CSVLoader object with Connection details. The
 * connection is closed on success or failure.
 * 
 * @param connection
 */
public CSVLoader(Connection connection) {
    this.connection = connection;
    // Set default separator
    this.seprator = ',';
}

/**
 * Parse CSV file using OpenCSV library and load in given database table.
 * 
 * @param csvFile
 *            Input CSV file
 * @param tableName
 *            Database table name to import data
 * @param truncateBeforeLoad
 *            Truncate the table before inserting new records.
 * @throws Exception
 */
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public void loadCSV(String csvFile, String tableName,
        boolean truncateBeforeLoad) throws Exception {

    CSVReader csvReader = null;
    if (null == this.connection) {
        throw new Exception("Not a valid connection.");
    }
    try {

        csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile), this.seprator);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new Exception("Error occured while executing file. "
                + e.getMessage());
    }

    String[] headerRow = csvReader.readNext();

    if (null == headerRow) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException(
                "No columns defined in given CSV file."
                        + "Please check the CSV file format.");
    }

    String questionmarks = StringUtils.repeat("?,", headerRow.length);
    questionmarks = (String) questionmarks.subSequence(0,
            questionmarks.length() - 1);

    String query = SQL_INSERT.replaceFirst(TABLE_REGEX, tableName);
    query = query
            .replaceFirst(KEYS_REGEX, StringUtils.join(headerRow, ","));
    query = query.replaceFirst(VALUES_REGEX, questionmarks);

    System.out.println("Query: " + query);

    String[] nextLine;
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        con = this.connection;
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);

        if (truncateBeforeLoad) {
            // delete data from table before loading csv
            con.createStatement().execute("DELETE FROM " + tableName);
        }

        final int batchSize = 1000;
        int count = 0;
        Date date = null;
        while ((nextLine = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {

            if (null != nextLine) {
                int index = 1;
                for (String string : nextLine) {
                    date = DateUtil.convertToDate(string);
                    if (null != date) {
                        ps.setDate(index++,
                                new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
                    } else {
                        ps.setString(index++, string);
                    }
                }
                ps.addBatch();
            }
            if (++count % batchSize == 0) {
                ps.executeBatch();
            }
        }
        ps.executeBatch(); // insert remaining records
        con.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        con.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new Exception(
                "Error occured while loading data from file to database."
                        + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (null != ps)
            ps.close();
        if (null != con)
            con.close();

        csvReader.close();
    }
}

public char getSeprator() {
    return seprator;
}

public void setSeprator(char seprator) {
    this.seprator = seprator;
}

}
```

this is Main.java

```
package id.co.lolo.coreservice;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class Main {

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static String JDBC_CONNECTION_URL = 
        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bni";


public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader(getCon());
        loader.setSeprator(';');
        loader.loadCSV("C:\\Log\\Logtima.csv", "coreservice", true);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static Connection getCon() {
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bni","root","shikamaru");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return connection;
}

}
```

I got this Error,

```
Query: INSERT INTO coreservice(MODULE_NAME,SERVICE_NAME,COUNTER,LOG_DATE,UPDATE_DATE) VALUES(?)
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1693)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1108)
    at id.co.bni.coreservice.CSVLoader.loadCSV(CSVLoader.java:118)
    at id.co.bni.coreservice.Main.main(Main.java:20)
java.lang.Exception: Error occured while loading data from file to database.Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
    at id.co.bni.coreservice.CSVLoader.loadCSV(CSVLoader.java:123)
    at id.co.bni.coreservice.Main.main(Main.java:20)
```

Comment: I seems that the number of fields doesn't correspond to the number of values. Indeed you have 5 fields (MODULE_NAME,SERVICE_NAME,COUNTER,LOG_DATE,UPDATE_DATE) and only one value(?) hence you got the error.

Comment: Use PreparedStatement instead of your complicated query. You can bind parameters and avoid SQL injection.

Comment: Does CSV file contain some // symbol or double quotes ?

Comment: halo there, when i marked this code ~> "loader.setSeprator(';');" I got this error ~> "Query: INSERT INTO coreservice(MODULE_NAME,SERVICE_NAME,COUNTER,LOG_DATE,UPDATE_DATE) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: No value specified for parameter 2" I am so confused, I think this happen because my csv file have semicolo as delimiter, any idea dude??

Comment: and when i give comma (,) as demiliter this program work well, maybe the problem is the program can't read semicolon (;) as demiliter!! but i got stuck :/

Comment: halo mr. oleg, yeah i got this symbol "/" for my date field!! any idea to fix it??

Comment: maybe your data in CSV file contain `;` character, so when you parse data and insert to database; it will insert more data then number of column you defined.

Comment: absolutely, my CSV file contain `;` character!! so I want to make `;` as my delimiter to parse data and insert to database, am i wrong??